# How can I get the list of mirrored packages to be showed in the devpi web application?

Tags: linux, python

I have two devpi instances in two machines. In one instance I created a mirror of an index existing in the other instance.

```
devpi index my-user/dev type=mirror mirror_url=http://<devpi_address>:<port>/my-user/dev/+simple/ mirror_whitelist="*"
```

After a while I can see that I have all my packages correctly mirrored but what doesn't work is the devpi web-ui. It happens that I can't have the list of the packages by clicking on the index url but it just shows the page saying `No packages whitelisted`.

If I search a package using the bar, it works. If I list the packages using the devpi cli, it works. The problem is just "visual". Has anyone experienced this and has an advice to share?

Thank you in advance!